# How to work with Django using Jupyter notebook

Tags: django, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to work in Django using Jupyter notebook. Could someone guide me in how to start working with Django. 
I have installed all the necessary components like django, django-extensions and django-admin and other plugins using pip, as well as checking the INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE in settings. I couldn't get to know, how to start working in a project. I normally work in Jupyter notebook.
Please let me know how to work Django in Jupyter notebook or suggest me other options. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If by "work" you mean "use Jupyter instead of Django shell", then you can use the following snippet in the first cell:

```
import sys, os
print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))

import django
print('Django %s' % django.get_version())

sys.path.append('<path to your project>')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<your settings module>')
if 'setup' in dir(django):
    django.setup()
```

I am also adding `/Users/soon/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/181.4445.76/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers` to the `sys.path` but unfortunately I can't remember why.

If you want to develop the website using Django, I'm afraid you can't. Use good IDE - e.g. PyCharm Pro